# How to use custom handler in optimizely 12?

Tags: asp.net-core, episerver, optimizely

We want to use custom handler such as Geta.NOTfound package handler for asp.net Core for Optimizely 12 project

I am trying to implement RewriteUrl(string url) method of NotFoundHttpHandler in ASP.net Core Optimizely12 project but facing compile time error

Comment: Also if handler is allowed in core.how do we move it in middleware

Comment: services.AddNotFoundHandler(o =>
 {
     o.AddProvider<NotFoundHttpHandler>();
 });

Comment: app.UseNotFoundHandler();

Comment: public string RewriteUrl(string url){var currentSite = _siteDefinitionRepository.List().FirstOrDefault(siteDefinition => siteDefinition.Hosts.Any(hostDefinition => hostDefinition.Authority.Hostname.Equals(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Request?.Host.Host)));var startPage = _contentLoader.Get<StartPage>(currentSite?.StartPage);
var redirectPageForBrokenPages=_urlResolver.GetUrl(startPage.RedirectPageForBrokenPages);if (currentSite == null || redirectPageForBrokenPages == null){_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 404; return null;
} return   redirectPageForBrokenPages;}

Comment: 'NotFoundHttpHandler.RewriteUrl(string)' cannot implement 'INotFoundHandler.RewriteUrl(string)' because it does not have the matching return type of 'RewriteResult'

Comment: I am facing this compile time error

Comment: The error you are getting is indicating the there is mismatch between the expected return type of the `RewriteUrl` method in the interface `INotFoundHandler` and the actual return type in your `NotFoundHttpHandler` implementation.make sure that your `RewriteUrl` method returns an instance of `RewriteResult` rather than just a string URL. I would like to request you to share the proper code in the original question. what you are implanting and what error you are getting and what is your expected result.